# Progress disapear on rotation android

Tags: java, android

I am using AsyncTask to download files. There i implemented progress:

```
//Updating progress dialog
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... changed) {
    progressDialog.setProgress(changed[0]);
}

//STARTED 
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    try {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMessage(context
                .getString(R.string.message_loading));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine in portrait and landscape. For notification that file was downloaded i am using interface.

So wrong is when i start downloading my file in portrait or landscape and while it not done i rotate device then progress disappear and callback fire exception as there is no where to go.

When i rotate device my Activity is re created, so how to do this properly. I need to restrict that when downloading is started user couldn't rotate device, then how to do that.

Or there are solutions to this ?

Comment: put android:configChanges="orientation"  in the manifest file for that activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict orientation while downloading then just before starting downloads use this code. this will restrict users device orientation.

```
int current_orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (current_orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
} else {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

This code you can use after finishing orientation which allow user to rotate device again.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: How to setRequestedOrientation in class which extends AsyncTask ?

Comment: use context.setRequestedOrientation. Where context is the context of the activity on which you are displaying your dialog.

Comment: I tried but this don't work. Compiler suggest to cast and when it does still show an error

Comment: use context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; it will give you orientation. That same orientation you need to set.

Comment: This worked ((Activity)context). Thank you for your time. Handling rotation on android is quiet hard work as  it recreates everything.

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation" this method is also fine but it breaks the regular life cycle of activity. So I think we should not use this..

Answer (score 1):

> I need to restrict that when downloading is started user couldn't
>   rotate device, then how to do that.

for this before you are are showing progress dialog you need to fix the device orientation.

```
onPreExecute(){
.....
.....
Activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
//in case activity started in landscape mode
progressDialog.show();
}
```

and once you are done with downloading.. you can resume to normal orientation changes.

```
onPostExecute(){
Activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

One more solution I will suggest..
Don't restrict the orientation for the activity, instead you can add "configChanges="Orientation"" attribute in manifest file and Please check for progressDialog object for !null in onPreExecute() method and setProgress(progress) if its not null.

```
onPreExecute(){
if(progressDialog!=null){
   progressDialog.setProgress(progress);
}
else{
......
......
}
}
```